# add elements to sub array using foreach in php

Tags: php

I have to add new elements to a sub array

I used the code to set values in a single depth array but now i have to add values to sub array

```
foreach($result["data"]  as  $val)
{
   $qry = "SELECT count(tin) as tincnt , count(tout) as toutcnt FROM inout 
   WHERE NAME = '".$val["NAME"]."'";
   $prs = oci_parse($conn,$qry);
   $exec = oci_execute($prs);
   oci_define_by_name($prs,"tincnt",$tin);
   oci_define_by_name($prs,"toutcnt",$tout);
   if(!$exec)
   {
        $result['STATUS']="error";
        $result['MESSAGE']="errcd 3 : error fetching data";
   }
   else
   {
         oci_fetch($prs);
         $val->{'TOTAL_IN'} = $tin;
         $val->{'TOTAL_OUT'} = $tout;
   }
}


$val->{'TOTAL_IN'} = $tin; // gives error Attempt to assign property of non-object
```

Input

```
{
     "data": [
      {
       "NAME1": "Sukhwinder",
       "PHONE1": "9516152737",
       "ADDRESS": "Jalandhar"
      },
      {
       "NAME1": "Sapna",
       "PHONE1": "8787878787",
       "ADDRESS": "Jalandhar"
      }
    ],
    "STATUS": "SUCCESS",
    "CNT": "2",
    "HASDATA": true
}
```

desired output

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "NAME1": "Sukhwinder",
            "PHONE1": "9516152737",
            "ADDRESS": "Jalandhar",
            "TOTAL_IN":5
            "TOTAL_OUT":4
        },
        {

            "NAME1": "Sapna",
            "PHONE1": "8787878787",
            "ADDRESS": "Jalandhar",
            "TOTAL_IN":4
            "TOTAL_OUT":4            
        }
    ],
    "STATUS": "SUCCESS",
    "CNT": "2",
    "HASDATA": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add values to the subarray (`$val` in your case), you have to pass it by reference. Try this:

```
foreach($result["data"]  as  &$val)
{
   $qry = "SELECT count(tin) as tincnt , count(tout) as toutcnt FROM inout 
   WHERE NAME = '".$val["NAME"]."'";
   $prs = oci_parse($conn,$qry);
   $exec = oci_execute($prs);
   oci_define_by_name($prs,"tincnt",$tin);
   oci_define_by_name($prs,"toutcnt",$tout);
   if(!$exec)
   {
        $result['STATUS']="error";
        $result['MESSAGE']="errcd 3 : error fetching data";
   }
   else
   {
         oci_fetch($prs);
         $val['TOTAL_IN'] = $tin;
         $val['TOTAL_OUT'] = $tout;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a key variable or a reference in the foreach loop.

**Key variable**:

```
foreach($result["data"] as $key => $val) {
  //[...]
  else {
    oci_fetch($prs);
    $result['data'][$key]['TOTAL_IN'] = $tin;
    $result['data'][$key]['TOTAL_OUT'] = $tout;
  }
}
```

Pro: you don't have to worry about unsetting the reference `&$val` via `unset($val);` behind the foreach loop

Con: much longer than reference syntax

**Reference**:

```
foreach($result["data"] as &$val) {
  //[...]
  else {
    oci_fetch($prs);
    $val['TOTAL_IN'] = $tin;
    $val['TOTAL_OUT'] = $tout;
  }
}
// this is important, because $val exists outside of the foreach loop
unset($val);
```

Con: you have to worry about unsetting the reference `&$val` via `unset($val);` behind the foreach loop

Pro: much shorter than key variable syntax

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php